# Firebase trigger return another node key for update call

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My database structure looks like this.  What I am trying to do is write a Firebase trigger that when any part of '/SCORES' node updates, it will get the RoundScore for the PlayerID and update the existing record.

```
"SCORES" : {
       "2017" : {
         "Round_1" : {
           "3" : {
             "Emoji" : "",
             "PlayerName" : "Person A",
             "RoundScore" : 100
               },
           },
       },
   },

"SELECTIONS" : {
    "2015" : {
      "Round_1" : {
        "TEAM A" : {
          "18" : {
            "emoji" : " ",
            "playerName" : "Person A",
            "position" : "POS"
          },
          "19" : {
            "emoji" : " ",
            "playerName" : "Person B",
            "position" : "POS"
          }
     },
        "TEAM B" : {
          "54" : {
            "emoji" : " ",
            "playerName" : "Person C",
            "position" : "POS"
          },
          "89" : {
            "emoji" : " ",
            "playerName" : "Person D",
            "position" : "POS"
          }
     },
        "TEAM C" : {
          "227" : {
            "emoji" : " ",
            "playerName" : "Person E",
            "position" : "POS"
          },
          "234" : {
            "emoji" : " ",
            "playerName" : "Person F",
            "position" : "POS"
          }
     },
        "TEAM D" : {
          "239" : {
            "emoji" : " ",
            "playerName" : "Person G",
            "position" : "POS"
          },
          "280" : {
            "emoji" : " ",
            "playerName" : "Person H",
            "position" : "POS"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So what I want the database to look like after the trigger.

```
"SCORES" : {
        "2017" : {
          "Round_1" : {
            "3" : {
              "Emoji" : "", <------------ DUPLICATE FROM HERE
              "PlayerName" : "Person A",
              "RoundScore" : 100 <------------ AND HERE
                },
            },
        },
    },

    "SELECTIONS" : {
        "2015" : {
          "Round_1" : {
            "TEAM A" : {
              "3" : {
                "emoji" : "", <------------ INSERT HERE
                "playerName" : "Person A",
                "position" : "POS"
                "RoundScore" : 100 <------------ AND HERE
              },
            },
        },
    }
```

So far what I've written only works for a hard coded teamID (TEAM A in the example above).

```
exports.whenScoresUpdate = functions.database
    .ref('/SCORES/{yearId}/{roundId}/{playerId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {  
        const newScoreData = snap.val();
        const yearId = context.params.yearId;
        const roundId = context.params.roundId;
        const playerId = context.params.playerId;
        const scoreObj = {
            "RoundScore" : newScoreData.RoundScore,
            "Emoji" : newScoreData.Emoji,
        }; 
    return admin.database().ref('/SELECTIONS/' + yearId + '/' + roundId + '/{teamId}/' + playerId).update(scoreObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are really not far from it!  The following code should work. Here are a couple of remarks:

- Since you want to trigger "when any part of '/SCORES' node **updates**", you should use another trigger that `onCreate()`, like `onUpdate()`. Note that you then have to use `change.after.val();` instead of `snap.val()`;.
- You have to find a way to set the value of `teamId`. This will not work: `...roundId + '/{teamId}/' + playerId....`
- You have to catch any possible `Promise.reject` from `update()`

---

```
    exports.whenScoresUpdate = functions.database
      .ref('/SCORES/{yearId}/{roundId}/{playerId}')
      .onUpdate((change, context) => {

        const newScoreData = change.after.val();

        const yearId = context.params.yearId;
        const roundId = context.params.roundId;
        const playerId = context.params.playerId;

        const teamID = "A"; //<- adapt according to your needs

        const scoreObj = {
            "RoundScore": newScoreData.RoundScore,
            "Emoji": newScoreData.Emoji,
        };

        return admin.database().ref('/SELECTIONS/' + yearId + '/' + roundId + '/' + teamId + '/' + playerId).update(scoreObj)
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                //...
            });

       });
```

Comment: Hi Renaud, yes if I hard code the team ID like you have `const teamID = "A";` it will work fine.  However this won't work for my application as I have 100s of scores that belong to players who live under multiple teamIDs.  So I need this to be variable on where the playerID lives in the SELECTIONS node

Comment: @AdamStewart it is difficult to help since it is really something that is purely dependent of your business needs. How do you know in which team(s) it should be written when you write to the SCORES node??

Comment: The SELECTIONS node has all relevant playerIDs already under each teamID. I've updated the original post structure to represent the greater amount of teams.

Comment: Ok, I got it. The easiest solution would be to duplicate the `teamId` value in the user sub-nodes in the node `SCORES`. This dernomalization is quite classic in NoSQL data modeling. Then you access it directly in your Cloud Function. The other way is to find, within your Function, the Team with a query to which you would chain the `update()` method.

Comment: In case a user is part of several teams, you could have a main node, with users sub-nodes that contains a list of all teams the user is belonging to. And then, again, in the Function, you start by querying this node to get the set of teams and then you write to the different `SELECTIONS/../../{team}` nodes with `update()`.

Comment: @AdamStewart Hi, did you finally solve your problem?